# Google Desktop's Ctrl,Ctrl feature on windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, google-desktop-search

One thing I like about Google Desktop is you can configure it so that when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, it will bring up a dialog that looks like this:

[image: Input box widget]

The dialog will have focus and I can type in there, press enter, and then it will open a new tab in my default browser using the contents of the text box.

For instance; this allows me to type
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, `foo`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
and it will open up this url: https://www.google.com/#q=foo

Is there a way to do this in Windows?
Failing that, is there a tool that will work like this?

Comment: Your question is asking for a software recommendation which is off topic.

Comment: @Sickest where's the appropriate place to ask?

Comment: not sure, i doubt anything like this exists anyway, so no point really. plus your question is way too broad, what exactly are you trying to search when you press cltr x2s? files or a web search?

Comment: @Sickest web search, as in the example.

Comment: you could add an address bar to your taskbar.

Comment: @Sickest what task bar?  I'm not trying to go to a website, I want to do a google search.

Comment: That website does not exist on this network.

Comment: made edit that asks for a procedure to get it implemented in windows, instead of asking for software recomendations

Comment: [SoftwareRecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) now exists for questions like this.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to do this with a script for AutoHotkey (Windows automation software). Just open notepad, paste the code below and save it with the **.ahk** file extension. I could only test it on Windows 7 though. But it opens the search URL on a new tab as expected. The search dialog box looks like this:

[image: this]

```
global MySearch
Gui, Margin, 9, 10
Gui, Font, s12
Gui, Add, Edit, vMySearch w400 -WantReturn
Gui, Font, c999999 s7
Gui, Add, Text, Y+3, Press <ctrl> twice to hide/show.

GuiEscape: 
    Gui, Hide

#ifWinActive Google Search 
NumpadEnter::
Enter::
    submitSearch()
    return
#IfWinActive

Ctrl::
    KeyWait, Ctrl
    KeyWait, Ctrl, D, T0.12
    if ErrorLevel = 0 
    {
        if WinActive("Google Search")
            Gui, Hide
        else
            Gui, Show,, Google Search
    }
    return

submitSearch(){
    Gui, Submit
    searchURL := "https://www.google.com/search?q=" . urlEncode(MySearch) 
    Run, %searchURL%
    GuiControl,, MySearch
}

urlEncode(url){
    VarSetCapacity(Var,StrPut(url,"UTF-8"),0),StrPut(url,&Var,"UTF-8")
    While Code:=NumGet(Var,A_Index-1,"UChar")
    Res.=(Chr:=Chr(Code))~="[0-9A-Za-z]"?Chr:Format("%{:02X}",Code)
    return,Res  
}
```

Comment: +1: it works fine. Is it possible to get [Google Search Autocomplete](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/106230?hl=en) in a dropdown box?

Comment: any idea why it opens empty google result when `#` symbol is used in search query?

Comment: Autocomplete would be too complex for me right now. But I edited the script to fix the # issue.

Comment: I was looking for the same functionality from long time; your AutoHotKey script is serving the purpose without bells & Whistles. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is create a [keyboard shortcut](http://lifehacker.com/5783366/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-launch-anything-in-windows) (without using any software!) to launch Chrome. Once you do that, you can hit the shortcut and when Chrome opens, it shows up with its address bar highlighted. Just type and hit enter.

Basically your exact use-case, except no middle-man (just type directly into the browser).

<sub>I don't think <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>, specifically, is possible (due to left/right `ctrl`s not being distinguished and just being control keys).</sub>

---

Should the link die you can create a keyboard shortcut (without third party software) by;

- creating an ordinary shortcut (type `chrome` into your start menu, `rightclick` on the icon -> `copy`, then `rightclick` in some folder -> `Paste shortcut`)
- go into the properties of the *shortcut* (`rightclick` -> `properties`), under the `Shortcut` tab there should be a `Shortcut key` field.
- type a key combination and hit `Ok`. That's it (the shortcut file will need to exist for the keyboard shortcut to continue to work)

---

As a further note, it turns out the result in the startmenu search for `chrome` *is* a shortcut, so you can skip the first step and just go into the properties *of the menu item* to add the `Key shortcut` field.

Comment: Did you use that feature? It's hard to explain how useful it is if you wasn't addicted to it. Unfortunately opening a new Chrome window is not an option. I used it very often, so this would lead to tons of opened chrome windows. It's bad as I usually try to group my tabs in different windows by some criteria. Plus other differences.

Comment: if you've already got chrome open and want the results as a new tab in a specific window then `Ctrl`+`T` is your friend

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do something similar to this (among other things) with the Open Source software [Launchy](https://www.launchy.net).

By default the shortcut to open the bar is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (You can change this but I don't think <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is possible...)

[image]

To google search you would type "google" TAB "foo" ENTER.

Comment: Exactly what my suggestion would've been. A short google search led me to believe Ctrl Ctrl isn't possible, but it also offered a solution: http://www.deanhouseholder.com/projects/launchy-ctrlctrl/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a version in Python using Tkinter:

https://gist.github.com/marczellm/9bb3a39c14fdf5a28c47ff132307aff6

Answer (score 0):

Try [FluentSearch](https://fluentsearch.net/) - it does exactly that: you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> then start typing.

(Later Edit) You can even customize the hotkey to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm looking for something that searches after typing `ctrl`, `ctrl`, not `ctrl` + `alt`

Comment: You can actually customize the hotkey to be Ctrl + Ctrl in Fluent Search, if that's really a showstopper for you. I'll update my comment with a screenshot.